# how to solve error due to wrong indentations in if statement loop

Tags: r, if-statement

I have this extended code containing within it an if-statement

```
list_final = lapply(seq(1:3), function(x) 
  lapply(seq(1:3), function(y) lapply(seq(1:2), function(j) {
        
        cols = colnames(data[[x]][[y]][1:ncol(data[[x]][[y]])])
        
        if (any(str_detect(cols, list_cond[[y]][j])) == T){
                datalist1[[x]][[y]] %>% 
                select(1:15, starts_with(list_cond[[y]][j]))
        } 
        else {
          next
          }  

     })
  ))
```

which is indentated exaclty as you could see. However I am getting the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

Which I assume related to indentation of else. Could you please suggest how could fix it? Thanks

Comment: `next` is for usage in a `for` loop and you have no `for` loop.

Comment: As it says in the error, there is "no loop for break/next"

Comment: The indentation in R is purely aesthetic. It doens't affect how the code is run. As already pointed out, the problem is that you are calling `next` which is only allowed in a for loop context. It cannot be used inside an `lapply`. Each call to a function inside an `lapply` must return a value. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: 12666727b9, [for the record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77215739/how-to-transform-the-wihtin-sublists-always-the-same-column-as-a-pivot-longer?noredirect=1#comment136125578_77215739), I did not downvote, and frankly I question the suggestion the validity of any comment suggesting you need to add that verbatim code. At most, provide unambiguous _language_ to the effect of _"starting with an empty enviroment"_ or similar, and yes _that_ might be justified in some situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R` you are always encouraged to use the `*apply()` family of functions because they are more efficient than `for` loops. What you are doing here, however, is just rewriting the `for (x in 1:3) ...` loops with `lapply(1:3, function (x) ...` instead of changing the logic.

It appears that you have a list of lists having elements that are data.frames, matrices or something similar in terms of indexing. If so, then you should start by writing your code like so:

```
list_final <- lapply(data, function(x)   # x == data[[x]], for each element of data[[]]
                lapply(x, function(y) {  # y == data[[.]][[y]]
                  cols <- colnames(y)

                  ...                    # list_cond, data_list1???

                  <<return something here>>
                })
              )
```

It's not obvious where `list_cond` and `datalist1` come from or what they look like so it's hard to finish that inner section of code but this is the general structure that you should follow.